# Atom Editor - Install Minimap Package on Windows

Tags: shell, command-line, atom-editor

I'm trying to install the minimap plugin (mimics the sublime minimap) for Atom Editor in Windows but when I do I get an error saying:

*"Packages that depend on modules that contain C/C++ code will fail to install. Run apm install --check... "*

On the documentation for the minimap it says to run:

```
   apm install minimap
```

When I try to run apm, it says command not found...

Online I've found other posts saying that you can go to the Atom toolbar and "Atom > Install Shell Commands" but on Windows there is no Atom toolbar, thats the Mac version as far as I know. Has anyone else had any success with this on windows?

I assume its something simple and I'm just missing it. I think what I need to do is get the apm command line tools to work to be able to run on my terminal so I can run "atom install minimap".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down.  I'm using Atom on windows and had the exact same issue.

Comment: If anyway you're looking on how to run `apm` from command line in Windows, this seems to go in the right direction: https://discuss.atom.io/t/cant-use-apm-atom-shell-commands-on-win-8-1/9818

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. Hopefully this helps some other poor lost soul.

In order to be able to install the minimap package you need to have [Python 2.78](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.8/)

By default the APM tool should be installed with atom, but if you do not have Python they will silently fail.

Next you need to have Visual Studio 2010 Installed with SP1.

You also need Git defined in your Windows Path Variable.

Once you have all these, Go to Atom Settings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> Type Settings, Search Packages for minimap, Hit install and it should install just fine.

Comment: why do we need Visual Studio 2010, you just need to have git in path that'all folks.

Comment: You may or may not need VS2010, if your having problems still when you have Git, try it and it might help, but I think @twntee is right and it most likely was not needed

Answer (score 0):

I will make everyone life easy. Follows these steps

1. Open "install" bar in atom.
2. Type "minimap" in searching for extensions.
3. Choose "minimap" in the first options and click install.

Viola minimap is active in service for you.